# Why is my macro opening up a prior excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code, and it works as intended but there's a small bug in which when I use it in another workbook it opens the excel file I wrote the macro in. I understand that setting the activeworkbook in the code itself can resolve the problem but I have a feeling something is still referencing the original file and I don't know where exactly it could be doing that. The goal is to use it in custom ribbons to share with my coworkers (I know that I can use addins and it avoids the problem but my workplace doesn't allow me to set my shared drive to use as a directory for addins for security reasons).

```
Sub vendorPECOCleaner()

Dim refi As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim aCell As Range, Rng As Range
Dim Row As Long
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

wb.Sheets(1).Name = "Raw Data"
wb.Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
wb.ActiveSheet.Name = "Refined"


Set refi = wb.Sheets("Refined")

refi.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

With refi
    Set aCell = .Range("A1:G20000").Find(What:="Invoice #", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

aCell.EntireColumn.Copy

refi.Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

End If
End With

refi.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"

For Row = 2 To 20000
    str1 = refi.Cells(Row, 2).Value
    str2 = Left(str1, 10)
    refi.Cells(Row, 2).Value = str2
Next Row

refi.Cells(1, 2).Value = "PECO Acc#"

refi.Range("A1").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you running the macro? Do you have the original file open when you run it? You should clarify your use of "worksheet" in your question too, do you mean workbook?

Comment: Right, I mean't to say workbook. I created the script above in another workbook but plan on using it in others through a custom ribbon button. When I use it in another workbook however, it opens the original I created the script in. I don't have the original file open when I run it and I don't want it to open, I just want the script to run in the current workbook I'm using it in.

Comment: Is the macro saved to a module or a "ThisWorkbook"? Additionally, if you're assigning variables to worksheets, there's no reason to activate them. It's actually better to not activate them. Just assign the variable and then manipulate the data using the variable without activating the sheet.

Comment: I got it! Thank you, I set it to a "Personal Workbook" and it resolved my issue. "ThisWorkbook" only works for when the original file is open so I'd want to set it to a "Personal Workbook."

Comment: Actually, it seems like it now makes the claim that it can't be found? I made sure the directory was correct. Also, if I don't activate and specify which workbook I'm working with it also affects the original.

Comment: A few things to note: 

1. Personal workbooks are saved by default in XLStart on your C drive

2. This isn't very useful in my case because my coworkers use a shared drive (S for the sake of this comment)

3. A ThisWorkbook macro does work but I still get the problem where it opens the original file

Answer (score 0):

If you got as far as I did and ran into the issues I described above you have a few options:

1. Create an Excel Add-in
2. Create a Personal Workbook macro
3. Create a ThisWorkbook macro but remember to close the original Workbook

1 and 2 work fine if the trusted locations includes a shared drive (mine did not) or if you're going to be using the same computer so that the macro being saved on your C drive isn't an issue (my coworkers use different computers). 3 allows you to leave the xlsm file in a shared drive because it's not bound to trusted locations and you can use it in a custom ribbon button if you wish. The only thing you must do is put the following line of code:

I figured out a solution that worked for me but is a weird way of going about it. Right before the end of the sub, close the original macro's workbook.

```
Workbooks("your_original_macro_workbook.xlsm").Close
```

Some users have suggested just editing your UI customization file but it never worked for me and while I suspect there's something strange going on with active workbooks, just closing the original seems before the end of your script seems to work even though it's a bit inelegant.